# Empty response when Node reads the file

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

Something I don't expect happen when I execute this code¹:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs").promises;
var server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  var data = fs.readFile('AcessedTimes.dat', 'utf-8')
  data.catch(err=>{
      fs.appendFile('AcessedTimes.dat', '0')
      .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
      .then(res.write("This is the first time this website is acessed!"))})
  .then(dat=>{
    if (dat != 0){
    res.write("This website was acessed {dat} times".replace("{dat}", dat));
    fs.writeFile('AcessedTimes.dat', (parseInt(data) + 1).toString()).catch(err=>{throw err});
    }
  });
  res.end();
})
server.listen(3000);
```

when I execute it at cmd:

```
C:\Users\<My User>\Node.js>node index.js
```

I got the error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
at C:\Users\Antonio Galvão\Node.js\index2.js:11:9
```

So, after some tests, I concluded that the problem is that the server ends before node reads the file and writes its content to response². So, I treated of putting "await" keyword before fs.readFile:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs").promises;
var server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  var data = await fs.readFile('AcessedTimes.dat', 'utf-8')
  data.catch(err=>{
      fs.appendFile('AcessedTimes.dat', '0')
      .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
      .then(res.write("This is the first time this website is acessed!"))})
  .then(dat=>{
    if (dat != 0){
    res.write("This website was acessed {dat} times".replace("{dat}", dat));
    fs.writeFile('AcessedTimes.dat', (parseInt(data) + 1).toString()).catch(err=>{throw err});
    }
  });
  res.end();
```

But, at console:

```
C:\Users\<My user>\Node.js\index.js:4
  var data = await fs.readFile('AcessedTimes.dat', 'utf-8')
             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I don't know what to do, because when I type this code directly to console:

```
C:\Users\Antonio Galvão\Node.js>
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.5.
Type ".help" for more information.
> fs = require('fs').promises
fs.readFile
[AsyncFunction: readFile]
```

Node says that fs.readFile is an AsyncFunction, but when I use await before this function, it says that the function isn't async!

What can I do to, at least, server return the value of the file before to close³?

Note ¹: The same thing occurs with "require('fs')"

Note ²: I concluded this because if I put "console.log("File loaded")" in the final of data.then brackets, "File loaded" **isn't** printed at console

Note ³: Plese, I don't want Timeouts or Intervals: they lag much and can give another error.

Comment: use writeFileSync, then dont use the .then or place res.end(); inside, basically your using async code but res.end(); is getting called before res.write(); happens, tip.. avoid .then at all costs, promisfy code which doesn't support promises, node [provides a helper/util](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) for standard callback code, else do `new Promse` if its not standard, then use async/await

Comment: Ok. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: your `res.end()` close the response stream befor you call `res.write()`. Use `res.end` after `res.write()` or replace `res.write` with `res.end`